# Linked Files in LD_LIBRARY_PATH statement not working

Tags: command-line, bash, qt, symbolic-link

Is there some magic to ensure that Link files work when part of a PATH statement?

I have an app that is looking for

```
/opt/Qt/5/gcc_64/lib/libXmlPatterns.so.5
```

The above file is a link to a file in the same directory that is:

```
/opt/Qt/5/gcc_64/lib/libXmlPatters.so.5.4
```

(I didn't write the app - I don't know why this is)

I have an env.sh that I call before running the app that contains this line:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/Qt/5.4/gcc_64/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

For some reason (and here's where I need help) the linked file is not picked up in the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` - I receive "No such file or directory"

Is this because it's a linked file, or may my problem be elsewhere?

Answer (score 0):

You are not giving the right path. You are giving :

```
/opt/Qt/5.4/gcc_64/lib
```

but there is no `/opt/Qt/5.4` directory from what you have mentioned earlier, the directory name is `/opt/Qt/5`

So giving the correct path should do :

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/Qt/5/gcc_64/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```